# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int' error in python

Tags: python

```
name = input("Въведете име: ")
Town = input("град: ")
school = input("Училище: ")
age= input("години: ")
hoby = input("Хоби: ")
sport = input("спорт: ")

print ("")
print ("Здравейте, казвам се" + name + " ,аз съм на " + age + "години.")
print ("")
print ("Аз живея в/във" + Town + ". " + "Уча в" + school + ".")
print ("Моето хоби е " + hoby + " ,и спортувам " + sport + ".")
print ("")
print ("Въведете 3 числа за триъгълника")
a = input("Страна А ")
b = input("Страна Б ")
c = input("Страна С ")
hc = int(input("Височината на триъгълника е "))
p = int(a) + int(b) + int(c)
S = int((c * hc) / 2)
print ("Периметъра на триъгълника е: " + int(p) + " ,a лицето е: " + int(S))
```

this is the code.

```
Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\B21pa\Desktop\Python\Homework\Homework-3\homework-3.py", line 20, in <module>
    S = int((c * hc) / 2)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: When you ask for help with an error, **always** share the **FULL** stack trace because that's what tells us which line caused the error instead of having to scour through your code to figure it out.

Comment: In this case, it's the line `S = int((c * hc) / 2)`. `c` is a string. When you multiply that with `hc`, you get a repeated string. Look up (or try for yourself) what multiplying a string with an integer does. Then you try to divide _that repeated string_ with an integer, which is an undefined operation. Python is not a statically typed language, so you need to be careful with variable types.

Comment: `c` is still a string, so `c * hc` is this string repeated `hc` times, which you try to divide. If your variables are supposed to be integers and not strings, convert them immediately when they get entered, not each time you use them, because the time always comes when you forget to do it...

Comment: Here are a couple of links you'll find useful: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to cast the inputs to `int()` where you explicitly expect them to be integers. All input captured from the terminal comes across as string. Attempting to add strings just concatenates them. Division is not supported on strings hence this error that `/` is an invalid operand for type `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code fixed should be:

```
name = input("Въведете име: ")
Town = input("град: ")
school = input("Училище: ")
age= input("години: ")
hoby = input("Хоби: ")
sport = input("спорт: ")

print ("")
print ("Здравейте, казвам се" + name + " ,аз съм на " + age + "години.")
print ("")
print ("Аз живея в/във" + Town + ". " + "Уча в" + school + ".")
print ("Моето хоби е " + hoby + " ,и спортувам " + sport + ".")
print ("")
print ("Въведете 3 числа за триъгълника")
a = int(input("Страна А "))
b = int(input("Страна Б "))
c = int(input("Страна С "))
hc = int(input("Височината на триъгълника е "))
p = a+b+c
S = int((c * hc) / 2)
print ("Периметъра на триъгълника е: " + str(p) + " ,a лицето е: " + str(S))
```

Comment: @JasarOrion you'd get more upvotes if you actually _explained_ what was wrong instead of just giving the code that will fix the problem. From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_